# Merge two datasets in R by date. The second dataset has "from" and "to" dates

Tags: r, merge

I have a large dataset in R with the following variables: Date, Country, ISIN.

For example:

> Date, Country, ISIN
>
> 11/03/2023, Germany, DE000BU27006
>
> 11/03/2023, Germany, DE000BU2Z015
>
> ...
>
> 11/03/2023, Denmark, DK0009923138
>
> 11/03/2023, Denmark, DK0009924532
>
> ...

Here ISIN denotes the government bond code. At any point in time a country has a 10 year benchmark bond and a 5Y benchmark bond. I have a table which specifies for each country the date range when a specific bond was benchmark bond.

So, I have a table with the following variables: Country, ISIN, Segment, FromDate, ToDate

For example:

> Country, ISIN, Segment, FromDate, ToDate
>
> Denmark, DK0009923807, 10Y, 03/05/2019,   03/05/2021
>
> Sweden, SE0007125927, 5Y, 06/30/2021, 08/03/2022
>
> ...

Then I want to merge information from the second dataset to the first dataset. In particular, in the first dataset I would like to add variable segment which is NA, 5Y or 10Y which would mean "not a benchmark bond on this day", "a 5Y benchmark bond on this day" and "a 10Y benchmark bond on this day".

Is there a smart way to do this rather than having many lines with if statements?
Thank you!

Comment: This is generically called an overlap join. Assuming you have first converted your dates from character to Date type, you could use `library(dplyr); first_data |> left_join(second_data, join_by(Country, within(Date,  FromDate, ToDate))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `merge` and make a comparison.

```
> merge(a, b) |> transform(foo=Date >= FromDate & Date <= ToDate)
  Country         ISIN       Date Segment   FromDate     ToDate   foo
1 Denmark DK0009924532 2023-11-03     10Y 2019-03-05 2021-03-05 FALSE
2  Sweden SE0007125927 2023-11-03      5Y 2021-06-30 2023-11-07  TRUE
```

Or, if you want the `NA`'s included:

```
> merge(a, b, all=TRUE) |> transform(foo=Date >= FromDate & Date <= ToDate)
  Country         ISIN       Date Segment   FromDate     ToDate   foo
1 Denmark DK0009923138 2023-11-03    <NA>       <NA>       <NA>    NA
2 Denmark DK0009924532 2023-11-03     10Y 2019-03-05 2021-03-05 FALSE
3 Germany DE000BU27006 2023-11-03    <NA>       <NA>       <NA>    NA
4 Germany DE000BU2Z015 2023-11-03    <NA>       <NA>       <NA>    NA
5  Sweden SE0007125927 2023-11-03      5Y 2021-06-30 2023-11-07  TRUE
```

You could also check out `data.table` which is very fast, and apparently you have lots of data.

```
> library(data.table)
> dat <- as.data.table(a)[as.data.table(b), on = c("Country", "ISIN")]
> dat[,foo := between(Date, FromDate, ToDate)]
> dat
         Date Country         ISIN Segment   FromDate     ToDate   foo
1: 2023-11-03 Denmark DK0009924532     10Y 2019-03-05 2021-03-05 FALSE
2: 2023-11-03  Sweden SE0007125927      5Y 2021-06-30 2023-11-07  TRUE
```

There should all `merge` question be covered: [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/6574038)

---

*Data:*

```
a <- read.csv(text='Date,Country,ISIN
11/03/2023,Germany,DE000BU27006
11/03/2023,Germany,DE000BU2Z015
11/03/2023,Denmark,DK0009923138
11/03/2023,Denmark,DK0009924532
11/03/2023,Sweden,SE0007125927
')

b <- read.csv(text='Country,ISIN,Segment,FromDate,ToDate
Denmark,DK0009924532,10Y,03/05/2019,03/05/2021
Sweden,SE0007125927,5Y,06/30/2021,11/07/2023')

a$Date <- as.Date(a$Date, '%m/%d/%Y')
b[4:5] <- lapply(b[4:5], as.Date, '%m/%d/%Y')
```